# How do I get simple anchors to work in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, anchor

I am no coder, but know enough HTML to get the job done.

I have simple anchors for in-page linking and they work in every browser but Chrome.

What is the average joe explanation of what I can do to get them to work?

[a title="Important Safety Information" href="#isi"] Important Safety Information [/a]

[a id="ISI" name="ISI"][/a]

Page with anchor link: http://educationexchangehcp.ndei.org/novo/bolus-insulin-type-2-diabetes-education-novo-nordisk.aspx
Click on Important Safety Information on the right.

Please help! Thank you,
Brian

Comment: Put at least 4 spaces before your lines of code to make them auto-formatted by Stack Overflow. Also, was it a typo in the question that you left off the first `<` and last `>` on the anchor elements' tags?

Comment: Sorry. I've never posted before. This is new for me.

Comment: @user3403541 No need to feel shy or attacked! I am merely trying to help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchor is in all caps, but the link is in all lowercase. Change the `<a id="ISI" name="ISI"></a>` to  `<a id="ISI" name="isi"></a>`. Also, if you're not using the ID tag for anything else, I'd just get rid of it. You don't need it for the anchor link to work.

Comment: Aha! That worked! Such an easy fix. Thank you very much CullenJ!

Answer (score 0):

HTML classes and ID names are case-sensitive. Change your code to `[a title="Important Safety Information" href="#ISI"]`.